# Collapsing margins not quite collapsing but ignoring background?

Tags: css, html

[image: hr clearly inside backgrounded div]

[image: parent ignores the margin]

[image: margin gets applied anyhow?]

Collapsing margins is a concept I presume to have understood. But I still find myself in cases where it just doesn't make sense to me.

Look at this `<hr />` (the green 3px high line). It is inside a container with a bright gray background (don't mind me naming it `bg-white`, there's a reason :X)

The `<hr />` get's a `margin-top` to create some space **inside** backgrounded area–

---

The parent completely ignores the margin.
But somehow the margin "breaks out of" the parent and still applies to the angled devider...

---

## I know...

I could just give the parent a padding. But I have my reasons not to do this.

---

`&nbsp;` right above the `<hr />` solves the issue, but seems really hacky and maybe mess things up when a user cranks up the browsers font-size.

---

Now why does the margin get applied accordingly but the background get's ignored?
The `<hr />` is clearly inside the light-gray-backgrounded `div`

---

- Can somebody explain to me why it is happening the way it is?
- Am I really forced to place some sort of spacer-element above the `<hr />`?

(pictured results coming from latest Safari on latest El Capitan)

Comment: Try: * {box-sizing: border-box}

Comment: It's not entirely sure goes wrong from your screenshots; you should really make a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. But the hr, with its top margin is the first child of the bg-white div, with its own top margin, right? Those two margins collapse too - they both have the same top margin.